# setInterval and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My current objective is to animate div elements by moving it by slightly every time interval. ( I want to do it without 'animate' feature of jQuery )

To do so, I first make array of elements like this:

```
var elements = $('.vz_container div.vz_element');
```

, and I use it like this in update function:

```
function update()
{
    for (var ei = 0; ei < elements.length; ++ei)
    {
        elements[ei].style.top += "10px";
        elements[ei].style.left += "10px";
    }
}
```

, and I create Interval like this:

```
setInterval(update, 1000);
```

Although, it seems 'update' function is indeed called every seconds, divs only move once on my screen and will stay there for the rest of the time.

I have no idea where it went wrong.

Comment: '10px' + '10px' is equal to '10px10px'.  Use `parseInt`

Comment: Aweary, Thanks for link to another useful thread, but you might want to consider that I was lacking needed knowledge to notice that duplication. Is it really necessary to punish someone for not being enlightened in stackoverflow?

Comment: Closing your question as a duplicate isn't 'punishment,' it's just that if a question has been answered before (and is sufficiently similar to *be* a duplicate) then there's no need to preserve your version of the question. If that question *doesn't* solve your problem edit an explanation of *why* that other question's answer, or answers, fails to address your own problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the string `10px` every time to the CSS properties, and not actually incrementing.

Instead, try:

```
function update()
{
    for (var ei = 0; ei < elements.length; ++ei)
    {
        elements[ei].style.top = parseInt(elements[ei].style.top) + 10 + "px";
        elements[ei].style.left = parseInt(elements[ei].style.left) + 10 + "px";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kierkegaurd: not sure about behavior of all browsers, in CSS unit has to be at left/top property.

Answer (score 1):

CSS in update function should work with integers, not strings. Now you only concatenate strings '10px' which makes invalid `left/top` values.

You need to use `parseInt` function to make an integer from left/top string property containing `'px'`.

```
function update() {
    for (var ei = 0; ei < elements.length; ++ei) {
        elements[ei].style.top = parseInt(elements[ei].style.top) + 10 + 'px';
        elements[ei].style.left = parseInt(elements[ei].style.left) + 10 + 'px';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As with the other answers you need to convert the value to an integer and then add 10.

But you will also need to specify a starting integer for this to work properly via the `style` attribute.

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vhxjo0e/)